# child process does not terminate?

Tags: process, signals

```
int a = 1;
void handler(int sig){
    a = 0;
}
void emptyhandler(int sig){
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    signal(SIGCONT, emptyhandler);
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        while(a == 1)
        pause();
        printf("a");
    }else{
        kill(pid, SIGCONT);
        printf("b");
        kill(pid, SIGINT);
        printf("c");
    }
}
```

I have an exam question about is there any processes do not terminate. 
I thought they will all terminate, so why there is process does not terminated?

Is it because the parent does not reap the child?

If parent end faster than child end, then there is no zombie process. 
but if child end faster than parent, then they will become zombies, am I right?

Comment: Does declaring `a` to be `volatile` fix it?

Comment: Even if the child becomes a zombie, it will be reaped when the parent exits, because it will be adopted by the `init` process, which will then reap it.

Comment: So you mean all process will terminate?

Comment: Unless they go into an infinite loop.